# Spring Data Rest OpenJpa - child collection not available

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, openjpa, spring-data-rest

I have a simple spring data rest example project with a single entity which has a collection of child entities of the same type:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();

    private String name;
```

I also have some simple test data set up. Person1 has two children: Child1 and Child2. When I access my REST resource for Person1 with

> http://localhost:8080/people/1

I get - as expected:

```
{
  "name" : "Person1",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people/1"
    },
    "person" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people/1"
    },
    "personList" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people/1/personList"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I follow the link to get my "personList":

> http://localhost:8080/people/1/personList

but unfortunately there is nothing returned although I expect a list with two elements of type Person.

**IMPORTANT INFORMATION:** I use OpenJpa instead of Hibernate. When using Hibernate in the same setup, the REST service returns the expected resources.

I also had a look at the generated SQL output: Hibernate makes two SELECT statements

```
select person0_.id as id1_0_0_, person0_.name as name2_0_0_ from Person person0_ where person0_.id=?
select personlist0_.Person_id as Person_i1_0_0_, personlist0_.personList_id as personLi2_1_0_, person1_.id as id1_0_1_, person1_.name as name2_0_1_ from Person_Person personlist0_ inner join Person person1_ on personlist0_.personList_id=person1_.id where personlist0_.Person_id=?
```

whereas OpenJpa makes only one statement.

```
SELECT t0.name FROM Person t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [params=?]
```

With OpenJpa somehow the "personList" part of the URI is not resolved. At least the query for the list is missing.

Does anyone know how to handle child collections with Spring Data Rest and OpenJpa?

I would really appreciate any help on this.
Cheers Chris

**EDIT:**

If I use **FetchType.EAGER** on the child collection, the link to the "personList" property can be resolved. OpenJpa is joining the children in its single SQL statement.

```
SELECT t0.name, t1.PERSON_ID, t2.id, t2.name FROM Person t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN Person_Person t1 ON t0.id = t1.PERSON_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN Person t2 ON t1.PERSONLIST_ID = t2.id WHERE t0.id = ? ORDER BY t1.PERSON_ID ASC [params=?]
```

The problem: I do not want to use eager loading because the final object can get pretty big.

Comment: This worries me as well. I would prefer OpenJPA or any other JPA provider to Hibernate but it seems that no-one at Spring is interested. Did you raise a bug?

Comment: No, I did not open a bugreport. According to the response rate, people are not really interested in supporting OpenJPA problems

Comment: I can appreciate that. I am interested in the potential performance compared to hibernate, but haven't got far enough with spring-data-jpa to start playing with possibly buggy options :(